# IDEA 14 and Grails 3.x unindexed remote maven repositories found

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-3.0

I am importing a new Grails 3.0.1 application into IU 14.1.1 and receiving a warning that "unindexed remote maven repositories found":

[image: Unindexed remote maven repositories found]

Opening the repositories list and clicking update as suggested does not seem to do anything.

[image: Indexed Maven Repositories]

IDEA does not have Grails 3.x support yet according to this issue: [IDEA-136970 Support for Grails 3.0](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136970).

Is there a workaround or should I just disable the warning until official support is released?

Comment: Seems like this indexing attempt really chews up system resources while on my company vpn...

Comment: Just a suggestion, From your snapshot above, select maven and set maven  path to your local path of maven and things should go fine, my notification went off with this and I feel that is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the release notes for [14.0.3](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+14.0.3+Release+Notes) you should disable the notification and will be fine. Bug #[134203](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134203)